# My Framework: Collection of unknown subclasses (hotspot)

Tags: c++, templates, vector, collections, subclass

I have this weird problem in which I want to have a collection of sub-classes of the class Script. But the thing is I can't know the type of this sub-classes because they're programmed by another person (It's a kind of a hotspot for my framework). So I used a template function but this is not my strong thing and it gives me an Unresolved external symbol.
I don't even know how to search this on other questions in SO.
Here's the code that tries to add the subclass of Script to the Scripts vector:

```
template <class T>
T* GameObject::addComponent()
{
    T *t = new T(this);
    Script *s = dynamic_cast<Script*> (&t);
    if (s)
    {
        scripts.push_back(t);
        return t;
    }
    return nullptr; 
}
```

It is casted to Script to prevent other kinds of objects being trapped by this generic function.
It is called like this:

```
Cube->addComponent<myScript>();
```

Where myScript is subclass of Script.
Please correct me if I'm programming horrible code!

Comment: Apart from your issue, you are leaking `t` if the dynamic_cast fails.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you have something like this for `MyScript`:

```
class MyScript : public Script
{
    ...
};
```

Then `GameObj` can just receive a pointer to a `Script`:

```
GameObject::addComponent(Script * s)
{
    scripts.push_back(t);
}
```

And you'd call it like this:

```
cube->addComponent(new MyScript);
```

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is I'm maintaining the use of the template functions and calling it with addComponent<Camera>() for example, and it works when I know the type in GameObject, but in this case I don't. Perhaps it is wrong that I want to maintain this usage of the templates?

Comment: (Sorry for the late reply...) Yeah, as far as I can tell, you shouldn't need templates at all to do what you're trying to do. Plain old _inheritance_ should be enough.